# Ubuntu 15.04 no longer mounts samba share on boot

Tags: server, mount, samba

I recently upgraded to ubuntu server 15.04 from 14.04.  I have this line in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
#Samba
//192.168.1.101/mediaserver2/ /mnt/mediaserver/ cifs  user=*****,password=*********,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix 0 0
```

*yes, i know that this isn't 'safe' putting password in `/etc/fstab` but this machine isn't connected to anything but my local network, it's just for me to mess around with*

Manually typing `sudo mount -a` after booting will mount the samba share, but I don't understand why it isn't loading on boot anymore.  Thank you for any insight into what's going on.

Comment: I have same problem, you can see for answer if any. http://askubuntu.com/q/696341/294611

Answer (score 2):

This may be a problem with the newly introduced systemd.

Adding `x-systemd.automount` to the option of the cifs entry in the `/etc/fstab` file solved this problem for me. Note the drive won't be mounted until you access it (by doing `ls` or similar).

Your fstab should look like:

```
//192.168.1.101/mediaserver2/ /mnt/mediaserver/ cifs user=*****,password=*********,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000,nounix,x-systemd.automount 0 0
```

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1458100