# NFS shares no longer mount on startup

Tags: fstab, nfs

I have an NAS device and mount several directories on it via entries in `/etc/fstab` :-

```
# NFS
number0:/projects /home/carl/number0/projects nfs rw 0 0
number0:/carl /home/carl/number0/stuff nfs rw 0 0
number0:/Qmultimedia /home/carl/Music nfs rw 0 0
number0:/Photos /home/carl/Pictures nfs rw 0 0
```

Recently (possibly since an update although I'm not sure), the NFS shares are not mounting on bootup, and I have to mount them with `sudo mount -a`.

As I've used the same fstab entries since Ubuntu 10.04 (maybe earlier), I suspect that there has been some change to the fstab standard that I no longer comply with.

There are numerous questions on AU about NFS not automounting but all relate to much older versions of Ubuntu, apart from [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625715/ubuntu-15-04-no-longer-mounts-samba-share-on-boot), which does not seem relevant.

Edit: the output of `sudo zegrep -w nfs /var/log/*` is

```
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:16 number2 ureadahead[214]: ureadahead:/var/lib/nfs/.etab.lock: No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:16 number2 ureadahead[214]: ureadahead:/var/lib/nfs/.xtab.lock: No such file or directory
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:16 number2 kernel: [    4.974103] systemd[1]: Job nfs-blkmap.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:20 number2 kernel: [   19.287387] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:26 number2 mount[767]: mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server number0: Temporary failure in name resolution
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:26 number2 mount[770]: mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server number0: Temporary failure in name resolution
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:26 number2 mount[773]: mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server number0: Temporary failure in name resolution
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:26 number2 mount[774]: mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server number0: Temporary failure in name resolution
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:35:26 number2 mount[775]: mount.nfs: Failed to resolve server number0: Temporary failure in name resolution
/var/log/syslog.7.gz:Jul  8 19:42:50 number2 kernel: [  470.817815] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
```

The NFS server is number0, which has been up and running the whole time (I have another machine also connected to the same NFS shares).

```
carl@number2:~$ ping number0
PING number0.home (192.168.1.65) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from number0.home (192.168.1.65): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.364 ms
```

Edit 2: @waltinator asked me to check the existance and permissions of these directories

```
carl@number2:~$ ls -l /var/lib | grep nfs
drwxr-xr-x 5 statd         nogroup       4096 Jul 21 17:55 nfs

carl@number2:~$ ls -l /var/lib/nfs | grep v4recovery
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root    4096 Apr 27 23:05 v4recovery
```

Edit: the shares actually appear in Nautilus but are unmounted.

Comment: And the log files say? `sudo zegrep -w nfs /var/log/*` would be step 0.

Comment: Do you not see the 5 areas for YOU to investigate on your system? Check that `/var/lib/nfs/`and `/var/lib/nfs/v4recovery` exist with correct ownership/permission, check `systemd` job `nfs-blkmap.service` (probably in `/etc/init/`) for depending something that is not available,  try to understand why, at `mount.nfs` time, you get the `Temporary failure in name resolution` (where does `number0` get resolved?) Does your NFS resolver try some other method first?

Comment: The 1st two directories exist (see edit).   `/etc/init` does not contain `nfs-blkmap.service`.  I don't know where `number0` gets resolved or what my NFS resolver is.  However, I've just booted the machine up and the NFS shares have mounted automatically, despite me not changing anything.

Comment: I would suggest to use **_netdev** in `/etc/fstab` entry option; http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169697/116970.  It seems the NFS share are mounted too earlier in the boot process.

Comment: @solsTiCe  The `_netdev` option does not make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried changing from server name (number0) to IP (192.168.1.65)?

It seems that at the mount time there is a problem in the name resolution.

For example change from:

```
number0:/projects /home/carl/number0/projects nfs rw 0 0
```

to

```
192.168.1.65:/projects /home/carl/number0/projects nfs rw 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Blame systemd. It was likely in your recent update. It needs to be explicitly told to wait for network stuff to be ready before attempting to mount.

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Good explanation [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NFS#Mount_using_.2Fetc.2Ffstab_with_systemd).