# Problem mounting samba shares in 15.10 (it worked in 15.04 !!)

Tags: mount, 15.04, samba, 15.10

With **15.04** (running inside **VirtualBox**), I used the technique descibed [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and it worked fine.

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

Now, in **15.10** (still inside the same VirtualBox setup), this does not work anymore. I get an error message at boot and the shares are not mounted. They can however be mounted manually with 'sudo mount -a'.

The error messages :

```
[   22.497984] CIFS VFS: Error connecting to socket. Aborting operation.
[   22.498336] CIFS VFS: vifs_mount failed w/return code = -101
```

This suggest a network error but I do not see why, except perhaps because this is running within **VirtualBox**? But again, the same method worked before.

Then I tried adding the '**x-systemd.automount**' flag like I saw in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/625715/ubuntu-15-04-no-longer-mounts-samba-share-on-boot):

```
//servername/sharename  /media/windowsshare  cifs  username=msusername,password=mspassword,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,x-systemd.automount  0  0
```

I still get the error messages at startup but surprise! ... it sort of works. The share is indeed mounted on the correct mount point and I can acesss it fine. However, on the Gnome desktop, where I have specified that I want to see the mounted volumes using the tweek tool, I see my shares twice but with 2 different types of icons:
[Click to see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPjXn.png).
When I do not use the 'x-systemd.automount' and do 'sudo mount -a' manually, only the lower kinds of icons appear.

I also tried various other combinations of additional flags (like using a credentials file or setting the 'gid=xxxx,uid=xxxx' flags) but it does not change anything.

Does anyone knows a way to fix this ?

Comment: Hi guys, an answer would be nice ...

Comment: I have asked same question, you can look for answer if I got any :-)  http://askubuntu.com/q/696341/294611

Comment: @edward: Thanks. Hope we'll get an answer. This prevents me from migrating to 15.10

Comment: you have used right solution `noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=3` thats how it works with `systemd` and the problem with two icons is just a bug in current desktop environment

Comment: I found the solution and also explained why our old method does not work.  http://askubuntu.com/a/697252/294611

Answer (score 0):

(answered wrong question)

Don't know if this helps, but I am using 15.10 and I mounted an external drive by editing the /etc/fstab file.

My drive is mounted by placing this at the end, you would have to change it according to whatever is appropriate for your system.

```
/dev/sde1 /media/external ntfs uid=nobody,gid=users 0 0
```

Comment: While this works for actual drives, OP needs a network drive to be mounted. Syntax is different. Not going to downvote this answer, but please do note this is not correct

Comment: Oh yeah, I misunderstood the question as wanting to mount a drive to be shared by Ubuntu.