# unable to mount samba share on boot (ubuntu 15.10)

Tags: boot, mount, samba, fstab, systemd

I am following [MountWindowsSharesPermanently](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently/#Special_permissions) to mount a samba share on boot
As said in wiki, I added these lines to `/etc/fstab`:

```
# auto-mounting the samba share 'Seagates' on raspberry pi
//192.168.2.2/Seagates /home/edward/samba/raspberry cifs uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/home/edward/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

and after that, since it is a password protected share, I added login credentials in `~/.smbcredentials` and rebooted

The mount is failing with these errors, taken from `journalctl | grep samba`:

```
Nov 10 22:39:27 flippingbits systemd[1]: Mounting /home/edward/samba/raspberry...
Nov 10 22:39:33 flippingbits systemd[1]: home-edward-samba-raspberry.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Nov 10 22:39:33 flippingbits systemd[1]: Failed to mount /home/edward/samba/raspberry.
Nov 10 22:39:33 flippingbits systemd[1]: home-edward-samba-raspberry.mount: Unit entered failed state. 
Nov 10 22:39:58 flippingbits smbd[2613]: pam_unix(samba:session): session closed for user nobody
```

However if I mount using `sudo mount -a` after boot, it works.

**NOTE:** On the same page ([here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently/#Unprotected_network_folder_won.27t_automount)) they have showed a work around to add `username=guest` to solve this problem. But I cant do it because I am mounting it as another user which is written in `~/.smbcredentials`

**I am on Ubuntu 15.10**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Ubuntu Wiki I have mentioned in question is bit outdated and does not works properly with `systemd`. systemd was first introduced in Ubuntu 15.04
The problem can be anything, by the time `/etc/fstab` is read the network would not be up OR by the time `/etc/fstab` is read `samba` services would not be ready OR it can be anything, I didn't read logs much.
But basically the method shown in wiki does not work.

After roaming on web, I finally found the solution and it is to add `x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=3,` before the rest of the options in `fstab` file

This:

```
//192.168.2.2/Seagates /home/edward/samba/raspberry cifs uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/home/edward/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

will become

```
//192.168.2.2/Seagates /home/edward/samba/raspberry cifs x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.device-timeout=3,uid=1000,gid=1000,credentials=/home/edward/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
```

What happens is if the drive is not mounted on first try, systemd will wait before it gives up trying to automount. This also does not affect/increase the boot time since systemd does not wait for this to complete and keeps loading rest of the system.